# How to register new user without need to login?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I have problem with registering new user on my OpenFire server. This is a reply from server.

```xml
<iq id='XILKN-9' to='pc-pc/b529612d' from='192.168.21.107' type='error'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <password>123</password>
    <email>bear@bear.com</email>
    <username>bear</username>
  </query>
  <error type="modify">
    <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

But when I login with any existing user before registering new user, I can register new user successfully and this is the reply from server

```xml
<iq id='XILKN-15' to='kkk@pc-pc/Smack' from='pc-pc' type='result'></iq>
```

Here is my code :

```java
String user ="bear";
String pass = "123";
String email = "bear@bear.com";
HashMap<String,String> attr = new HashMap<String, String>();
attr.put("username",user);
attr.put("password",pass);
attr.put("email", email);
if(conn2!=null) {

    Registration reg = new Registration();
    reg.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
    reg.setTo(conn2.getServiceName());
    reg.setAttributes(attr);
    PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(
            reg.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
    PacketCollector collector = conn2 .createPacketCollector(filter);
    try {
        conn2.sendPacket(reg);
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IQ result = (IQ) collector.nextResult(SmackConfiguration
            .getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
    System.out.println(result);
    collector.cancel();
```

I used OpenFire 3.9.3 and aSmack 4.0.7 .

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correct I solve this issue by the next steps.

1. creat connection with the server.
2. then you use with `AccountManager`
3. then you create new account by `createAccount`

So with should be something like that:

```
 AccountManager am = connection.getAccountManager();
                     Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     attributes.put("username", username);
                     attributes.put("password", password);
                     attributes.put("email", email);
                     attributes.put("name", name);
                     try {
                        am.createAccount(username, password,attributes);
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User create: " + username,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```